# Talend how to connect the tfileInputDelimited to tjava and tLibraryLoad and get the changes reflect in tfileOutputDelimited

Tags: talend

tfileInputDelimited has the 3 fields
id name text

tfileInputDelimited --iterate---> tjava --row-> tfileOutputDelimited

how can I get the the text field in tjava so that the changes that done in tjava can be reflected in outputfile.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with `iterate` from tFileInputDelimited instead of `row` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `tJavaRow` component instead of `tJava`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i want to use tjava i have already done with tjavarow.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to tJavaRow is to use tMap in the same manner than @xto specified.